# RingCentral Fax Coverpages

Tags: fax, ringcentral

I am using a single page document to Fax, can when I fax it using the **RingCentral Fax API**, it by default includes a blank cover page. I do not want any cover page for my fax, how can I eliminate it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the RingCentral Fax API and want to eliminate the Coverpage from your fax document, you can achiieve it as below

1. While calling the Fax API make sure to set the  coverIndex parameter to 0.
   (use the GET /restapi/v1.0/dictionary/fax-cover-page endpoint to understand what each coverIndex means. )

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms Setting **coverIndex = 0** to disable cover page.
This parameter is actually ***optional*** in the API.
As per API reference here: "***If not specified, the default cover page which is configured in 'Outbound Fax Settings' is attached***"

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Fax/createFaxMessage

As per this link, "***When using these demos, the fax API coverIndex parameter should be set to 0 so that no cover page is added.***"

https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-demos-fax-cover-page#ringcentral-fax-api-configuration-parameters